# Array count logic error

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

Made some edits to the code to try and figure out why my X's [-1] are not being included in finding my average for that row. That is throwing of my averages. Any idea why It is not counting my -1's?

output[expected]:

```
USER INPUT: 3
O O O 
X X X
X X X 

TOTAL OPENNESS OF [I][J] = 1
TOTAL OPENNESS OF [I][J+1] = 2
TOTAL OPENNESS OF [I][J+2] = 1
TOTAL SUM AVERAGE FOR THAT ROW = 1.3
HOWEVER..FOR ROW 2 AND ROW 3 
TOTAL SUM AVERAGE FOR THOSE ROWS = 0  
WHICH IS INCORRECT IT SHOULD = -1
```

```html
public static void openfactor(char[][] mazeValue, int n){

       for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
       {  
           double rowAvg=0;
           double totalRowAvg=0;
           for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
          {

              int count=0;
              int totalOpeness=0;
              int totalRowOpeness = 0;
              //double rowAvg=0;

               if(mazeValue[i][j]=='X'){
                   System.out.println("tHIS IS AN X FOR : [" + i + "]" +"[" + j + "] IS -1 ");
                   count = -1;
               }

              else 
               {
               //YOU NEED TO VERIFY THAT J IS NOT OUT OF BOUND
               if( j-1>=1)
                    {
               if(mazeValue[i][j-1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                      // System.out.println("cout: "+count);

                    if(i-1>=1 && j-1>=1)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i-1][j-1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                     //  System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                     if(i-1>=1)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i-1][j]=='O')
                        count++;
                     }
                    //   System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                    if(j+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i][j+1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                     //  System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                    if(j+1<=n && i+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i+1][j+1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (i+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i+1][j]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                    //   System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                    if(j-1>=1 && i+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i+1][j-1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(i-1>=1 && j+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i-1][j+1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                     //  System.out.println("cout: "+count);
            totalOpeness = totalOpeness +count;
            System.out.println("TOTAL OPENESS FOR : [" + i + "]" +"[" + j + "]  IS " +totalOpeness);
            totalRowOpeness = totalRowOpeness + totalOpeness;
            //}//eND OF iF CONDITION\
            }
               
            rowAvg = (double)totalRowOpeness/(double)n;
            System.out.println("ROW AVERAGE: "+rowAvg);
            totalRowAvg = totalRowAvg + rowAvg;
            System.out.println("SUM ROW AVERAGE: "+totalRowAvg);
         }
        System.out.println("TOTAL SUM ROW AVERAGE: " +totalRowAvg);
      }
   }
    public static void printMaze(char mazeValue[][]) {
    System.out.println("MAZE");
    for (int i = 1; i < mazeValue.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < mazeValue[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%5c", mazeValue[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("ENTER A SINGLE INTEGER: ");
    int n = kbd.nextInt();
    char[][] mazeValue = new char[n + 1][n + 1];
    System.out.println("ENTER A PATH: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < mazeValue.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mazeValue[i].length; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == n + 1 || j == n + 1)
                mazeValue[i][j] = 'X';
            else {
                mazeValue[i][j] = kbd.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }
    }
    printMaze(mazeValue);
    horizontalPath(mazeValue, n);
    System.out.println(" ");
    verticalPath(mazeValue,n);
    System.out.println(" ");
    openfactor(mazeValue, n);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand what u want to accomplished but I am going to to assume you want to find repeated values, do this using some search algorithm below is an example of a binary search. Hope it helps.

```
      import java.util.Scanner;

   class BinarySearch 
  {
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int c, first, last, middle, n, search, array[];

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of elements");
    n = in.nextInt(); 
    array = new int[n];

    System.out.println("Enter " + n + " integers");


    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
      array[c] = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter value to find");
    search = in.nextInt();

    first  = 0;
    last   = n - 1;
    middle = (first + last)/2;

    while( first <= last )
    {
      if ( array[middle] < search )
        first = middle + 1;    
      else if ( array[middle] == search ) 
      {
        System.out.println(search + " found at location " + (middle + 1) + ".");
        break;
      }
      else
         last = middle - 1;

      middle = (first + last)/2;
   }
   if ( first > last )
      System.out.println(search + " is not present in the list.\n");
  }
    }
```

Comment: No you don't need binary search.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete code for your request. you need to reorder your if statements a little bit your logic was right:
and here is the output :

```
    MAZE
    O    O    X
    O    O    O
    X    X    O
TOTAL OPENESS FOR : [0][0]  IS 3
TOTAL OPENESS FOR : [0][1]  IS 4
THERE IS AN X HERE FOR : [0][2]  
Average of O's in this row is : 66.66667%
TOTAL OPENESS FOR : [1][0]  IS 3
TOTAL OPENESS FOR : [1][1]  IS 5
TOTAL OPENESS FOR : [1][2]  IS 3
Average of O's in this row is : 100.0%
THERE IS AN X HERE FOR : [2][0]  
THERE IS AN X HERE FOR : [2][1]  
TOTAL OPENESS FOR : [2][2]  IS 2
Average of O's in this row is : 33.333336%
```

here's the code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class sof {



public static boolean IsOutOfBound(int i, int j, int n)
{
if (i-1<1 || j-1<1 || i+1>n || j+1>n)
return true;
else
return false;

}

public static void openfactor(char[][] mazeValue, int n)
   {


   for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
   {      

       int TotalCounts=0;
       for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
      {

          int count=0;


           if(mazeValue[i][j]=='X'){
               System.out.println("THERE IS AN X HERE FOR : [" + i + "]" +"[" + j + "]  ");
               //TotalCounts--;
           }

           else 
           {
           //YOU NEED TO VERIFY THAT J IS NOT OUT OF BOUND

           if( j-1>=0)
                {
           if(mazeValue[i][j-1]=='O')
                    count++;
                }
                  // System.out.println("cout: "+count);

                if(i-1>=0 && j-1>=0)
                {
                if(mazeValue[i-1][j-1]=='O')
                    count++;
                }
                 //  System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                 if(i-1>=0)
                {
                if(mazeValue[i-1][j]=='O')
                    count++;
                 }
                //   System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                if(j+1<n)
                {
                if(mazeValue[i][j+1]=='O')
                    count++;
                }
                 //  System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                if(j+1<n && i+1<n)
                {
                if(mazeValue[i+1][j+1]=='O')
                    count++;
                }
                if (i+1<n)
                {
                if(mazeValue[i+1][j]=='O')
                    count++;
                }
                //   System.out.println("cout: "+count);

                if(j-1>=0 && i+1<n)
                {
                if(mazeValue[i+1][j-1]=='O')
                    count++;
                }
                if(i-1>=0 && j+1<n)
                {
                if(mazeValue[j+1][i-1]=='O')
                    count++;
                }
                 //  System.out.println("cout: "+count);

                //totalOpeness = totalOpeness +count;
        System.out.println("TOTAL OPENESS FOR : [" + i + "]" +"[" + j + "]  IS " + count);
        TotalCounts++;



                }//END OF else CONDITION
            }//End of J loop
             float Average = ((float)TotalCounts/(float)n) * 100;
             System.out.println("Average of O's in this row is : " + Average+ "%");
       }//End of I loop

       }





    public static void printMaze(char mazeValue[][],int n) {
    System.out.println("MAZE");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%5c", mazeValue[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("ENTER A SINGLE INTEGER: ");
    int n = kbd.nextInt();
    char[][] mazeValue = new char[n][n];
    System.out.println("ENTER A PATH: ");
    for (int i = 0; i <n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            //if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == n + 1 || j == n + 1)
             //   mazeValue[i][j] = 'X';
           // else {
                mazeValue[i][j] = kbd.next().charAt(0);
           // }
        }
    }
    printMaze(mazeValue,n);
    openfactor(mazeValue, n);
}
}
```

Comment: You need to reset the value of count and totalOpeness after the first loop

Comment: I dont have java installed on my machine that's why i asked for outputs and other stuff, i will try to use JFiddler or something similar

Comment: That would be awesome, I can not tell you how long I have been stuck on this portion my program.

Comment: You will need to add more if statements , you need to have 9 conditions to verify the position. i will review them later

Comment: Actually its only 8, I dont need to consider the element it self just the surrounding. It almost works except if a X leads to an O it needs to return -1, I think other than that its ok, let me check.

Comment: Why did you comment out the X check if statement?

Comment: so that's easier, i wasn't sure what do you want do if it found an X. initially i had it to display "This is an x at i,j" then i changed it to display all the O's surrounding it

Comment: yes you are right it's 8 conditions. i need to run now. i will check it out later if you are still having problems

Comment: @JaredWildox 
 
Don't forget to mark the answers if it works for you

Comment: I tried to mark the answer it is not working correct, I made some changes to for finding the average of every row. It is not counting my X values for the average, any idea why?

Comment: What i s not working exactly and also what kind of average exactly do you wanna count

Comment: Do you wanna count the average of X per row?

Comment: I want to count the average of all of my openfactors  including the X (-1) not sure why I can't get a correct average

Comment: example if row 1 = 1 -1 2 3 1 than my avg = 1.2

Comment: @JaredWildox I edited the code a little bit . i think this is a good base for you to work on and finish your task.

Comment: Thanks man, I actually got it, I have a question to ask though, should i store my int's for my openfactor in an array?

Comment: it depends on how do you want to use them, if you want to reuse them later then yes if not(You need the value just temporarily), then don't use array. 
Once again don't forget to mark the answer :)

Comment: I keep trying it wont let me! :/

Comment: you need to post your code in order to see what's not working.
Is this part of a homework?